# Does spark-streaming run multiple foreach in parallel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

In this case

```
val dStream : Stream[_] = 
dStream.foreachRDD(a => ... )
dStream.foreachRDD(b => ... )
```

Do the foreach methods :

1. run in parallel?
2. run in sequence but without specific order?
3. The foreachRDD( a => ) before the foreachRDD( b => )?

I want to know that because I want to commit kafka offset after a database insert. ( And the db connector give just a "foreach" insert )

```
val dStream : Stream[_] = ...().cache()
dStream.toDb // consume the stream
dStream.foreachRDD(b => //commit offset ) //consume the stream but after the db insert
```

In the spark UI it's look like there is an order but I'm not sure it's reliable.

Edit : if foreachRDD( a => ) fail , do the foreachRDD( b => ) is still executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DStream.foreach` is deprecated since Spark 0.9.0. You want the equivalent `DStream.foreachRDD` to begin with.

Stages in the Spark DAG are executed sequentially, as one transformation's output is usually also the input for the next transformation in the graph, but this isn't the case in your example.

What happens is that internally the RDD is divided into partitions. Each partition is ran on a different worker which is available to the cluster manager. In your example, `DStream.foreach(a => ...)` will execute before `DStream.foreach(b => ...)`, but the execution within `foreach` will run in parallel as regards to the internal `RDD` being iterated.

> I want to know that because I want to commit kafka offset after a
>   database insert.

The `DStream.foreachRDD` is an output transformation, meaning it will cause the Spark to materialize the graph and begin execution. You can safely assume that the insertion to the database will end prior to executing your second `foreach`, but keep in mind that your first `foreach` will be updating your database in parallel foreach partition in the `RDD`.

Comment: Yes sorry a said foreach but I would mind foreachRDD.
The parallelism is pretty well explain in documentation, but not the "DStream fork"
So responce 3.
If the foreachRDD( a => )  do the foreachRDD( b => ) will be executed any way? ( I should edit ma question for this )

Comment: @crak I didn't understand your last question.

Comment: Imagine the database insert fail, do the second instruction ( the offset commit ) still be done ?

Comment: So it's not the ideal way to go :x.
A callback on foreachRDD or maybe have a saveToDb as a transformation would be better.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I think your assumption is wrong here as the db insert may take more time than commiting kafka offset. crak, you are right that if the db insert fails then also second foreach will be done provided no exception is thrown from first foreach.

Comment: @amit_kumar Where did I say it'll take more time? I said their execution is sequential

Comment: Execution of the code inside foreachRDD will not be sequential, it will be executed parallely. To verify that check for the DAG that is prepared for such code. I have checked this in JAVA and it should behave same for all languages.

Comment: @amit_kumar You haven't understood my answer. *"In your example, DStream.foreach(a => ...) will execute before DStream.foreach(b => ...), **but the execution within foreach will run in parallel as regards to the internal RDD being iterated**."*. I said execution within the foreach is parallel. Was that not clear?

Comment: My point was on this statement of yours "You can safely assume that the insertion to the database will end prior to executing your second foreach", you can't assume safely here & nothing more than that.

Comment: @amit_kumar I'll edit my answer in regards to exceptions

Comment: Don't fight ^^
So foreach are executed sequentialy, but if the second foreach is still executed when the first crash, the maneuver is fruitless. Offset will be committed when db fail and event will not be replay.
So in this exemple a good stream should have just one foreachRDD materializer I think.

Comment: I don't see it as fruitless, if you implement your own failure handling mechanism from the driver (wrap method with Try() then catch at job end. At job launch you could 
 also commit the target offsets and assign your job an ID. As you launch multiple jobs in parallel you can check this. HDFS files are mutable, so you could append to a text file on hdfs or a separate kafka topic. As you encounter a failure you would not write a success status. You would need a custom job launch as well but all of this seems within the bounds of something a large company might need.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple DStream.foreachRDD are not guaranteed to execute sequentially atleast till spark-streaming-2.4.0. Look at this code in JobScheduler class:

```
class JobScheduler(val ssc: StreamingContext) extends Logging {

  // Use of ConcurrentHashMap.keySet later causes an odd runtime problem due to Java 7/8 diff
  // https://gist.github.com/AlainODea/1375759b8720a3f9f094
  private val jobSets: java.util.Map[Time, JobSet] = new ConcurrentHashMap[Time, JobSet]
  private val numConcurrentJobs = ssc.conf.getInt("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", 1)
  private val jobExecutor =
    ThreadUtils.newDaemonFixedThreadPool(numConcurrentJobs, "streaming-job-executor")
```

The JobExecutor is a thread pool and if "spark.streaming.concurrentJobs" is set to a number more than 1, there can be parallel execution if enough spark-executors are available. So make sure your settings are correct to elicit a behavior you need.